# How to edit an existing eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an open source plugin, with a license that allows me to modify it, from here: http://www.jcraft.com/eclipse-jcterm/ (under the source section). I want to modify this plugin and use it on my local eclipse.

1. Is this even possible given the jar file that I have? Or do I need more?
2. What must I do to bring this up in eclipse (via the Eclipse plugin development view obviously)?
3. How can I install this plugin to verify it works as I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download the plug-in JAR to somewhere.
2. In Eclipse, File->Import->Plug-ins and Fragments
3. Select the directory you saved it in, select 'Projects with source folders', Next
4. Add the plugin, Finish

You now have an Eclipse project representing the plugin.  Make your changes, and then:

1. File->Export->Deployable plug-ins and fragments
2. Select the plug-in, select a place to save it

I don't know of a way to do development on a plug-in that is 'live' in your instance of the IDE, so I think you'd have to install it to your copy of Eclipse by dropping it in the plugins directory, then restart.

Comment: What about dependencies? When I export the plugin I do not have the dependent jar files bundled.

Comment: @Zombies I don't see any dependent JARs in the original plugin, so this is a new JAR that you're adding correct?  You need to tell the plugin about the dependency.  First add the JAR(s) to the project in a lib folder for example.  Then, go to the plugin.xml Runtime tab, and add them to the plugin manifest.  When you export the plugin, it should include that folder and the contents thereof, as well as including them in the classpath when the plugin gets loaded and executed.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has special environment for plugin development: [PDE](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/). Here's a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html) on how to develop a simple plugin.

I think [this instruction](http://pydev.org/developers.html) is quite relevant, it explains how to start contributing to PyDev and starts with an explanation on how to setup the environment.