# Eclipse Plugin Development - ClassCastException cannot cast abc.xyz to abc.xyz

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-pde

I am currently developing a plugin in Eclipse. I have encountered a problem with the following code:

```
XYZ object1 = XYZ(object2);
```

where the said line throws an exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: abc.XYZ cannot be cast to abc.XYZ

---

XYZ class is from another plugin. Unfortunately, the said plugin does not have its packages visible. So, setting it as a dependency threw a `ClassDefNotFound` exception.

Luckily, I have the `.jar` of the plugin and added it to my plugin's build path. When I did so, it still returned a `ClassDefNotFound` exception. I looked around and found out that for plugins, the referenced libraries are not 'detected' by the JVM automatically, and so, I followed the solution to add the said jar to the `MANIFEST.MF` and to the `bin.includes` section of my plugin's `build.properties`.

After following the said solution, I tried again and now I have classCastException. Atleast, at this point, the class `XYZ` from the jar file is now being loaded. Doing some research, I found out that the classloaders of both `XYZ` classes are different. I am quite stuck on what steps should I do.

Here's the summary of the whole problem:

- Required class is from another plugin. Said plugin does not have classes visible.
- Added the dependency plugin's jar file to the build path.
- ClassDefNotFoundException is thrown.
- Updated my plugin's manifest.mf and build.properties config.
- ClassCastException is thrown.

It would be great if anyone has a solution to this problem or any inputs on what I can do to fix this.

Thank you in advance for any help/input that will be provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. The Eclipse plugin system is designed to prevent you accessing classes which are not exported.

Including the plugin jar in your plugin will always use a different class loader from the class loader and you will get the class cast exception.

The only way to access these classes is for the other plugin to be modified to export these classes.

Comment: I am currently editing the other plugin following this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448509/how-to-edit-an-existing-eclipse-plugin. However, I cannot export it. It is not showing in the export wizard. Any ideas?

Comment: What isn't showing? 'File > Export > Deployable plugins and fragments' should always show if you have the Plugin Development Environment installed. Note that if the plugin has been signed modifying it will give errors.

Comment: The plugin that was imported isn't showing in the 'Deployable Plugins and Fragments' dialog.

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about this as it is not something I ever do.